# Google Calendar API - Stop watching events

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client, service-accounts

I am creating an app to interact with Google Calendars and want to watch resources, but I also want the ability to stop watching them.

When I try to un-watch I get the error `Error calling POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/channels/stop: (403) Incorrect OAuth client`

I am using a service account and OAuth 2.0 to authenticate myself and have other API calls that work absolutely find so I know I am authorized. What am I doing wrong?

These are some of the working API calls...

```
public function getEvents($calendarId, $opts = array())
{
    $events = $this->calendarService->events->listEvents($calendarId, $opts);
    return $events;
}

public function getEvent($calendarId, $eventId)
{
    $event = $this->calendarService->events->get($calendarId, $eventId);
    return $event;
}

public function watch($calendarId, $channelId, $listener)
{
    $channel = new Google_Service_Calendar_Channel($this->client);
    $channel->setId($channelId);
    $channel->setType('web_hook');
    $channel->setAddress($listener);

    $watchEvent = $this->calendarService->events->watch($calendarId, $channel, array());
    return $watchEvent;
}
```

This is the stop API call...

```
public function stopWatch($channelId, $resourceId)
{
    $channel = new Google_Service_Calendar_Channel($this->client);
    $channel->setId($channelId);
    $channel->setResourceId($resourceId);

    $watchEvent = $this->calendarService->channels->stop($channel);
    return $watchEvent;
}
```

Any ideas on how to get this working?

Answer (score 2):

You need to instantiate the service from the client and then the channel from the service.  There may be a shortcut, but the code below works.

```
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
$channel =  new Google_Service_Calendar_Channel($service);
$channel->setId($channelID);
$channel->setResourceId($ResourceID);

try
{
    $service->channels->stop($channel);
}
catch(Exception $e)
{   
    error_log("Caught exception in killWatch ",0);
}
```